# Does internal traffic go back to modem router?

Tags: wireless, ethernet, dhcp

Hoping to get some help regarding a small office network being set up.

We've got a modem/router that's handling DHCP connected to an AirPort Time Capsule which is bridged/handling the wireless network side of things. The modem/router is connected to the APTC via 100mbit ethernet.

My question is, does that mean local traffic on the Wi-Fi connection is limited to 100mbit? Will internal traffic move from the AP back to the router because it is the one handling DHCP? Or is it smart enough to happen on the AirPort?

Just wondering as all devices are Wireless AC!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Wi-Fi connection is limited to 100mbit?

Yes. That's the AP's only access to anything else.

> Will internal traffic move from the AP back to the router because it is the one handling DHCP?

No. Any traffic between wireless clients will only pass through the AirPort.  Traffic will flow back to the router because that's what the AP is connected to -- assuming there's any non-wireless nodes in your network, and it's the path to the internet.

Comment: Thanks for that! So if I'm moving files on LAN between two AC Wireless clients only, it should go as fast as the APTC can go? (Faster than 100mbit). Only traffic that goes to the web etc would be limited to the 100mbit ethernet? Cheers!